# How do I get a subView to completely cover the screen?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

Here's my first view:
[alt text http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/9904/screenshot20100630at857.png](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/9904/screenshot20100630at857.png)

When I call `[self.view addSubview:theSubviewController.view];` I get this:
[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8199/screenshot20100701at944.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8199/screenshot20100701at944.png)

See how it does not completely cover the first view?  The UI controls respond to clicks on the left half of the screen where the view background is, but they do not on the right side of the screen.  In the view controller, I have enabled `shouldAutoRotateToOrientation`.  What do I need to do to correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow that's embarrassing.  I needed to select the view controller in Interface Builder and uncheck "Resize view from NIB".